# How can I assign users to certain seed data?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following data in my `seeds.rb` file:

```
users = User.create([
    {
      :email => 'user1@email.com', 
      :password => 'test', 
      :password_confirmation => 'test'
    },
    {
      :email => 'user2@email.com',
      :password => 'test',
      :password_confirmation => 'test'
    }
    ]) 
puts 'Users added'

UserPrice.create([
  {
    # assign user 1
    :product_name => "Great Value Vitamin D Whole Milk",
    :price => '3.81',
    :purchase_date => Date.strptime("08/25/2011", "%m/%d/%Y"),
    :store => "New York"},
  {
    #assign user 2
    :product_name => 'Eggs',
    :price => '2.78',
    :purchase_date => Date.strptime("08/25/2011", "%m/%d/%Y"),
    :store => "New York"
  }
])
puts 'Added Prices'
```

**How do I assign the rightful users to the `UserPrices` in my seeds.rb?**

Note: I tried to do `:user => users.first` but that didn't work.

---

**Working Code:**

```
user1 = User.create(:email => 'user1@email.com', :password => 'qweasd', :password_confirmation => 'qweasd')
user2 = User.create(:email => 'user2@email.com',:password => 'qweasd',:password_confirmation => 'qweasd')

user1.user_prices.create(
    :product_name => "Great Value Vitamin D Whole Milk",
    :price => '3.81',
    :purchase_date => Date.strptime("08/25/2011", "%m/%d/%Y"),
    :store => "New York"
    )
user2.user_prices.create(
    :product_name => 'Eggs',
    :price => '2.78',
    :purchase_date => Date.strptime("08/25/2011", "%m/%d/%Y"),
    :store => "New York"
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to do this more along these lines:

```
user = User.create(#stuff#)
user.user_prices.create(#stuff#)
```

Assuming a has_many relation.